# Execute fortran with more than one thread

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I am working with a FORTRAN.77 program with a lot of iterations in a lot of loops in Ubuntu/Linux with gfortran, and to compile and execute it I simply use

```
gfortran program.f 
./executable.out
```

By using htop while the execution, I see only one of the cores is working on that process.
Is there any option/flag one can use in the compilation or in the execution to force it to use more than one core/thread so it will be much faster?

Comment: The most common parallel frameworks for Fortran are [OpenMP](https://www.openmp.org/) and [MPI](https://www.open-mpi.org/). Many tutorials for both exist around the web.

Comment: By default Fortran codes are not parallel, and you will have to have to put some coding effort in to make them parallel as @veryreverie implies. But while not parallelizing compiling with `gfortran -O3 program.f` will almost certainly give you a noticeable speed increase - learn how to use your compiler!

Comment: These days Fortran has intrinsic facilities (`coarrays`) to support parallel programming, OpenMP and MPI are not the only route to take.